# DevBridge JQuery Autocomplete not working in Chrome for Android

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using Autocomplete script from DevBridge in my WP plugin.
It works just great on all browsers and all devices except for Chrome for Android: suggestion list won't come up.
I would think I'm doing something wrong, but my codes work in Chrome for Windows.

Anyone else stumbled upon something similar?

Here's the code:

```
<input type="text" name="job_search" id="job_search" class="job_search" tabindex="1" />
```

Then my JS:

```
$("#job_search").keypress(function(e){      

  if (e.which !== 13) {

      $("#job_search").autocomplete({

              serviceUrl: this.href,
              type: 'POST',
              paramName: 'ac_query',
              deferRequestBy: 300,
              minChars: 3,
              onSearchComplete: function(query, suggestions){

                  },
              onSelect: function(selection){

                  $.post(this.self, {ac_selection:selection.data}).done(function(data){

                          data = JSON.parse(decodeURI(data));

                          $('#rate').prop('disabled', false);
                          $('#job_time').prop('disabled', false);
                          $('#add').prop('disabled', false);
                          $('#memo').prop('disabled', false);
                          jobNumber = data.pID;
                          jobDescription = data.description;

                      });
                  }
          });

  }

});
```

Then my php:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'  && isset($_POST['ac_query']) ){

$q1 = "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."ezts_projects 
        WHERE description LIKE '%".$_POST['ac_query']."%' 
        OR pID LIKE '%".$_POST['ac_query']."%' AND open = 1 LIMIT 5";
$result = $wpdb->get_results($q1);

$jsondata = '{ "query" : "'.$_POST['ac_query'].'", 
"suggestions": [
';
for($j=0; $j < sizeof($result); $j++) {

    $jsondata.= '{ "value" : "'.$result[$j]->pID.' - '
                    .$result[$j]->description
                    .'", "data" : "'.$result[$j]->pID.'" }';
    if( $j < (sizeof($result) - 1) )$jsondata.=",
";
}
$jsondata.='] }';

print_r($jsondata);
die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing keypress event did the trick.

```
$("#job_search").autocomplete({

              serviceUrl: this.href,
              type: 'POST',
              paramName: 'ac_query',
              deferRequestBy: 300,
              minChars: 3,
              onSearchComplete: function(query, suggestions){

                  },
              onSelect: function(selection){

                  $.post(this.self, {ac_selection:selection.data}).done(function(data){

                          data = JSON.parse(decodeURI(data));

                          $('#rate').prop('disabled', false);
                          $('#job_time').prop('disabled', false);
                          $('#add').prop('disabled', false);
                          $('#memo').prop('disabled', false);
                          jobNumber = data.pID;
                          jobDescription = data.description;

                      });
                  }
          });
```